# Problemas con getUpdates - Bots Telegram

Tags: python, telegram

estoy iniciado en los bots para telegram, ya que trabajo mucho con esta red social y quiero automatizar algunos mensajes, estoy haciendo mi primer bot y no me funciona. Me sale este error

telegram.error.Conflict: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Error while getting Updates: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: lee [ask]. (Comentario aparte: Telegram no es una red social, es una app de mensajería.) ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y compartir tu código _como texto, con formato_? Es para mejor legibildad. Puedes darle formato con el botón que indica `{}`.

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que pretendes es correr dos telegram bots en el mismo servidor o ordenador, a mi me funciona poner al principio un proxy y por cada bot poner un proxy diferente:

```
import os

proxy = 'http://162.255.201.37:8080'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
```

Esto si funciona, el problema es que los proxies son gratis y se desconectan cada dos por tres, así que no es una solucion tan efectiva, si encuentro otra te lo digo.
Un saludo

Comment: No explicas el por qué del problema ni el cómo de la solución. Es como si Harry Potter lo solucionara lanzando un hechizo.